# Romeo and Juliet Derived

Tags: probability

The question was that:
Romeo and Juliet have a date at a given time, and each, independently, will be late by amounts
of time, X and Y , respectively, that are exponentially distributed with parameter λ.
(a)Find the PDF of Z = X − Y by first finding the CDF and then differentiating.
in solution manual,question is dividing two parts whether z is equal or greater than zero or z is less than 0
first part of solution assumes z is equal to or greater than 0
$$ P(X \leq Y+z) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^{y+z}f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy $$ 
in first part integral exactly goes on.but in second part,

I don't understand second part of integration of change of bounds 
$$ P(X \leq Y+z) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^{y+z}f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy \\
=\int_0^\infty λe^{-λx}\int_{x-z}^\infty λe^{-λy} dydx$$

Sorry for my language mistakes,my native language is not English.

Comment: Where are the two parts? I see  one part only. The order of integragtion changes but both integrals calculates $P(X\leq Y+z)$.